# reading an integer from a string

Tags: c++, constructor

I am reading a date from the db as a string. I want to break it down into integers so I can pass it to my Date constructor, so I used the following:

```
 int y,m,d;
sscanf(test,"%d-%d-%d",&y,&m,&d);
cout<<"date is: "<<y<<"-"<<m<<"-"<<d<<"\n";
Date cdr;
    cdr=Date(d,m,y);
    setDate(cdr);
cout<<"cdr is "<<cdr.getDay();//this is returning 0
```

and here's the getDay()

```
inline int getDay(void) const {return d_;}
```

the problem is the cout shows the integers fine, but when I pass these to my Date constructor 
the output shows a bunch of numbers like this: 
1176523603-1162761289-1176531567

can you help me fix this...thx!

Comment: If the numbers are printing ok, the problem is most likely related to your Date class. Please show that code.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning the [`strftime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) function which creates a standard C `tm` structure.

Comment: @itcplpl: OK now show the code where you output the numbers. Best of all edit the post above to post a **complete** program. We get this all the time, newbies post code but always, always the error is in the code they didn't post. That is why you should post a complete program.

Comment: Retagged, explicit-constructor would lead me to believe you are speak of a constructor with the explicit keyword, not a constructor that you defined instead of letting the compiler generate it.

Comment: You still don't have the entire source code in the question.  It looks like the definition for `class Date` was in a comment that has since been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Date class posted in the comments above the error is here

```
class Date
{
...
Date(const Date& dd){}
Date& operator=(const Date&){}
...
};
```

Delete both of those methods and the code might work.

Comment: but why do I need to delete them?

Comment: Because they are used when your Date object is copied, but because you haven't defined them correctly they don't work and will cause the kind of bugs you are seeing. But you don't need to define them for your Date class because the compiler will define correct ones for you. You should read a book on C++ and read the section on copy constructors and assignment operators, it's an important topic, and one that newbies often get wrong.

Comment: can you point me to an example of how I can define it correctly

Comment: Do you mean for your Date class, or more generally? For your Date class the correct thing to do is not define them because the compiler will do the work for you. For more complex classes you do have to define them yourself, but how to do it correctly is a big topic, which is why I suggested you look at a good C++ book.

Comment: I meant generally if there was a good link online, I wouldn't have to wait to get a book ;-)

Comment: I did have a quick look, didn't find anything I would recommend unreservedly. This one seemed OK, http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/ and the next section http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/ I don't think it gets it all right, but many I looked at were just rubbish.